# Reflection and inheritance in Java

Tags: java, reflection

I have the following fragment of code:

```
class BaseClass {
    public Integer getX() {
        return 5;
    }
}

class InheritedClass extends BaseClass implements Interface {
}

interface Interface {
    public Number getX();
}

public class Test5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(InheritedClass.class.getMethod("getX").getReturnType());
    }
}
```

this code returns `java.lang.Number`, which is very strange to me, because BaseClass's `getX` method returns `java.lang.Integer`. And the most interesting is that if `BaseClass` implements Interface, the returned type is java.lang.Integer... Is this a normal behaviour?

Comment: I agree that this looks odd. But so does your entire inheritance arrangement. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I think happens.

By simultaneously extending `BaseClass` and implementing `Interface`, the subclass promises to provide two `getX()` methods:

```
public Integer getX();
public Number getX();
```

Since you can't overload on return type, there can only be one method. Furthermore, its return type has to be `Number` rather than `Integer` (since you can cast the latter to the former, but not vice versa).

To reconcile all of the above, the compiler automatically generates the following method in `InheritedClass`:

```
  public java.lang.Number getX();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokevirtual #22                 // Method getX:()Ljava/lang/Integer;
       4: areturn
```

As you can see, it has the signature of the method in `Interface`, but automatically delegates to the method in `BaseClass` (with an implicit upcast).

This automatically-generated method is what your reflection code is picking up.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually makes sense to me, seeing as you cant actually implement a `public Number getX() {...}` method in the inherited class. +1.

Comment: But what is changed inside the InheritedClass, when BaseClass implements the Interface, so then InheritedClass.getMethod().getReturnType() returns Integer?

Comment: @GeorgiGeorgiev: I *think* the `Interface -> Inherited` chain is ignored in favour of `Interface -> Base -> Inherited`, and the latter narrows the return type down to `Integer` through covariant return types. This is just a guess though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is normal:

- `Integer` is a subclass of `Number`
- As of Java 5.0, it is OK for a derived class or an interface implementation method in Java to return a subclass of the return type declared in the superclass or the interface. This is called [*return type covariance*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10134571/335858).
- Because `InheritedClass` implements the `Interface`, the return type of `getX` from that interface is used, namely, `Number`.

Comment: Ok, Inherited class implements the Interface, but new InheritedClass().getX() returns Integer, not Number...

Comment: @GeorgiGeorgiev an `Integer` inheriting `Number` means that an `Integer` *is a* `Number`, so `getX` returns a `Number` that *happens to be* an `Integer`.

Comment: covariant return types are perfectly fine, but what's going on here is contravariant return types. `InheritedClass.getX` returns a `Number` while `BaseClass.getX` returns an `Integer`. Return types are allowed to get *less* specific as you go up the hierarchy, not *more* specific.

Comment: @Jeffrey That is a different way of saying that return types are allowed to go *more* specific as you go *down* the inheritance hierarchy, right?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Correct, but in this case the return type is getting less specific as you go down the inheritance hierarchy. (`InheritedClass.getX` returning a `Number` is less specific than `BaseClass.getX` returning an `Integer`).

Comment: @Jeffrey No, that's the wrong hierarchy!!! `InheritedClass` does **not** override any of the methods in `BaseClass`. The only overriding that is going on in the OP is `InheritedClass` inheriting from the `Interface`, with the `getX` method from the `BaseClass` providing the implementation for that interface's `getX` by giving a method with a more specific signature, which is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant section of the JLS is [§8.4.8.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.4):

> It is possible for a class to inherit multiple methods with
>   override-equivalent signatures ([§8.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2)).
>
> If one of the inherited methods is not `abstract`... the method that is not `abstract` is considered to override, and therefore to implement, all the other methods on behalf of the class that inherits it.

The two methods we are considering here are:

- `public Integer getX();`
- `public abstract Number getX();`

Since`BaseClass.getX` is not `abstract`, and it is [return-type-substitutable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5) (`Integer` is a subclass of `Number`) for `Interface.getX`, `BaseClass.getX` is chosen to override `Interface.getX`.

Which is strange since that's not the result you are seeing. However, if you try to define a method `public Number getX()` in `InheritedClass`, you will receive an error, which is consistent with the above.

Answer (score -1):

This is a function of the Java framework 1.6 which includes Generics. Integer and Double are a subtype of Number.

Comment: How does this involve Generics?

Comment: Receiving the type number is due that is the superclass. You can use ? extends Number to put Interger and doubles into a list. ? super type Number for an actual type. It is all based on leveraging class properties and code resuse.