# Why does SSLSocketFactory.createSocket returns a Socket instead of SSLSocket?

Tags: java, jsse

In my code according to a boolean flag I should decide whether or not to handshake an SSL socket. I use the SSLSocketFactory to create the socket, and this is the signature of the createSocket method taken from the official Javadoc.

```
abstract Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose)
```

It appears a clear design  choice here to return a `Socket` and not an `SSLSocket`, that means that classes using this method wouldn't need to know that the `Socket` is an `SSLSocket`.

However, if I have to handshake it, I have to downcast it, because the method

```
  public abstract void startHandshake() throws java.io.IOException;
```

is defined on the SSLSocket class.

```
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket( getApiServerAddress(), getPort() );
```

Which of the three possible answers is correct?

- This design pattern in the library shows  you are not supposed to call startHandShake() directly but rather calling some method on the Socket class which will call startHandShake(). What is this method on the Socket class? And, if this is the case, why startHandShake() is public?
- The library is poorly designed.
- I am not creating an SSLSocket the right way.

Answer (score 3):

Because `createSocket` method is inherited from `SocketFactory`. It's impossible to override result type.

There could be a way around it using generics, but that would break existing API and all existing code.

Comment: You can override a result type with a subclass. It's called covariant return - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134571/covariant-return-type-in-java. However it was only introduced in Java 1.5 so probably SSLSocketFactory was designed before that

Comment: @boky It wouldn't break existing code - you can always pass a subtype where a supertype is expected (and the actual runtime type would always have been the same, even with the old method signature)

Comment: @artbristol No, it wouldn't compile time, I can agree. I am not quite sure about already compiled code though.

Comment: @artbristol But there is at least a risk of `NoSuchMethodError` when the signature changes.

Comment: @EJP Technically the return type isn't included in the method signature

Comment: @artbristol Technically changing the return type *will* produce a `NoSuchMethodError`. It just happened to me. Try it.