# I thought this would work because of covariant return types?

Tags: java, covariance

Class `Main` has a subclass `SubMain`.

Class `Foo` has a subclass `SubFoo`.

In `Main`:

```
public List<Foo> getFoo() { return null; }
```

In `SubMain`:

```
@Override
public List<SubFoo> getFoo() { return this.subfoo; }
```

I get a compiler error though on `List<SubFoo>`.  Am I thinking about this incorrectly?  Below are a couple sources that made me think this would work.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10134596/1747491

Comment: ```List<SubFoo>``` is not a subtype of ```List<Foo>```. On the other hand ```ArrayList<Foo>``` would be a subtype of ```List<Foo>```, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider:

```
public List<? extends Foo> getFoo() { return null; }
```

As `Edwin` states, a `List<SubFoo>` is not a subclass of `List<Foo>` since you could not add of `Foo` to a `List<SubFoo>`.

Other options:

```
public class Main<T extends Foo>{
   public List<T> getFoo();
}

public class SubMain extends Main<SubFoo>{
  public List<SubFoo> getFoo();
}
```

or make `SubMain` return a `List<Foo>`

Comment: Your first suggestion definitely works!  What is fundamentally different about it though?

Comment: Because of the `? extends` wildcard, your API is stating that it is returning of `List` of SOME type that extends `Foo`. The users of this list will be able to retrieve elements and be guaranteed that these elements will be `Foo` instances. However, since the `List` is potentially of some subtype of `Foo`, users of the list will not be able to add anything to the `List` because they will not know what would be the appropriate type to add (you can't add a `Foo` to a `List<SubFoo>`.

Comment: FYI, conversely the `? super` wildcard allows for insert but not retrieval.

Answer (score 1):

`List<SubFoo>` is not a subtype of `List<Foo>`, but `ArrayList<Foo>` is a subtype of `List<Foo>`.

See `Generics` [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html) ,

### SOLUTION:

You can do something like `List<? extends Foo> getFoo()`

See `Wildcards and Subtyping`[link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html) for more