# Avoid casting in inherited java-classes

Tags: java, inheritance, casting

I have a class:

```
class MyClass {

  public MyClass getParent() { ... }

  public MyClass[] getChildren() { ... }

  ....

}
```

and a subclass

```
MySubClass extends MyClass {

  public String getId() { }

  ...
}
```

Everytime I used `getChildren()` or `getParent()` on an instance of `MySubClass`, I have to cast the result of theese methods, e.g.:

```
MySubClass sub = new MySubClass();
((MySubClass)sub.getParent()).getId();
```

Is there any way (by language or design) to avoid that casting?

Thanks for any ideas!

**Update**
What I would like is that `getParent()` and `getChildren()` always return the type of the instance they are called from, e.g. `sub.getChildren()` should return `MySubClass[]`

Comment: it is a mandatory casting because MyClass has not getId() method.

Comment: Do you intend for `MySubClass` instances to only have `MySubClass` parents and children? Or would it be legal for a `MySubClass` to have a `MyClass` child or parent?

Comment: how do you know the parent will be of type `MySubClass`?

Comment: Why is casting such a problem for you?

Comment: @HotLicks if it's unnecessary, it's just noise

Comment: @jacobm: `MySubClass` instances only have `MySubClass` parents and children.

Comment: @herman - It's not unnecessary.  And there are lots of things that are "noise" in programming.

Comment: @HotLicks It's unnecessary if he knows the type in question will always be the same (`MySubClass`) and if it can be avoided.  Of course a lot of things are "noise", but noise decreases readability so should be avoided.

Comment: But all of the proposed "cures" introduce even more "noise".  Programming is often about making trade-offs, and in many cases a simple cast is preferable to a more complex and incomprehensible "solution".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the self-type pattern:

```
class MyClass<T extends MyClass<T>> { 
  public T getParent() { ... }
  public List<T> getChildren() { ... }  // you can use an array here too, but don't :)
}

class MySubclass extends MyClass<MySubclass> {
  public String getId() { ... }
}
```

You can implement your `getParent` and `getChildren` methods as desired, declare fields in `MyClass` that hold `T` references and know that they behave at least as `MyClass` references, et cetera. And if you call `getParent` or `getChildren` on a `MySubClass`, you can use the return values as `MySubClass` instances with no casts anywhere.

The primary disadvantage of this approach is that people who haven't seen it before tend to get pretty confused.

Comment: Thanks for that idea. I have a problem with that (dummy example code): `public T getThis() { return this; }` gets an error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from MyClass<T> to T`. Do you have an idea?

Comment: If you want to implement `getThis()` in `MyClass` code, you'll need to add a cast: `public T getThis() { return (T) this; }`. You should also  suppress the unchecked-cast warning this cast will cause with the explanation that any object that calls this method will necessarily have a type bound above by `T`, so it's always safe to cast `this` to `T`.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any way (by language or design) to avoid that casting?

The answer is **No**. If you want to access super class field or method than you must explicitly cast.

Comment: You are right. My question was not so clear as I wish. Please see my update.

Answer (score 4):

Beginning with Java 5.0, you can override methods with *covariant return types*, i.e. you can override a method to return a subclass parent class. (see [Covariant return type in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134571/covariant-return-type-in-java)):

```
public class MySubClass extends MyClass {

  @Override
  public MySubClass getParent() {
    return (MySubClass) super.getParent();
  }

  @Override
  public MySubClass[] getChildren() {
    return (MySubClass[]) super.getChildren();
  }

  public String getId() {
    ...
  }
}
```

You can then call `new MySubClass().getChildren()[0].getId()`.

Of course this will only work if `MySubClass` always has MySubClass instances as parent and/or children

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assuming that you know that the parent and children of a `MySubClass` will always be of type `MySubClass`.

In that case you could just narrow the return types in `MySubClass` and do the casting there:

```
MySubClass extends MyClass() {
    @Overrides
    public MySubClass getParent() { return (MySubclass) super.getParent(); }

    @Overrides
    public MySubClass[] getChildren() { return (MySubclass[]) super.getChildren(); }

    public String getId() { }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using generics (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html)

You should have something like this:

```
public class MyClass<T extends MyClass> {

    public T getParent() { return null; }

    public MyClass[] getChildren() {
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass<MySubClass> o = new MySubClass();
        o.getParent().getId();
    }
}

class MySubClass extends MyClass<MySubClass> {

    public String getId() {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are actually trying to do, either make your base class abstract and add getId():

```
abstract class MyClass() {
    public MyClass getParent() { ... }
    public MyClass[] getChildren() { ... }
    public String getId();
    ....
}

MySubClass extends MyClass() {
    @Overrides
    public String getId() { }
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, depending on your requirements, implement getId() in your base class:

```
class MyClass() {
    public MyClass getParent() { ... }
    public MyClass[] getChildren() { ... }
    public String getId() { }
    ....
}

MySubClass extends MyClass() {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the method getId to the super class as well ie. MyClass.

Any subclasses can still override and have their own implementation.
If you are scared of subclasses not overriding getId,then throw an exception from the super class from getId.

Th erotically, getID is some thing that is applicable for All Class and hence can be added to super.

Comment: Sounds like getID is having too much fun.