# Common Interface with Different Return Types [Java]

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface

I'm trying to implement the `Command` pattern in various classes by extending/implementing the `Command` class which contains a single method `public void execute()`. However, down the line I noticed I need to implement a number of variations of the pattern to allow it to return different values such as `boolean` and other custom values. I would like all these classes to inherit/implement a single common interface that requires them to implement the method execute() (and perhaps several other methods) while giving each class the flexibility to add its own return type.

First I thought I could accomplish this with generics but this would not work - as it does not enforce the return type in the sub classes (it would allow for any return type).

Tech, I could create many "Command" classes (such as `BooleanCommand` + `StringCommand` + several other such classes with custom return types) but this would mean I need to design each class from scratch as they are not implementing a common interface. In other words, there's no way for me to have `BooleanCommand` implement the base class `Command` thereby forcing it to implement the method `execute()` while allowing it to have it's own return value of `boolean`. Similarly, I would like the `StringCommand` class to implement the base class `Command`  (thereby forcing it to implement the method `execute()` ) while allowing it to have `String` as a return value.

This might be fine if I had only one method in each class but what if I have several methods and no way to enforce this design?

How can I solve this design issue?

Comment: You should be looking at JDK 8 interfaces for lambdas and functional programming.  I think this problem is solvable with generics.

Comment: You can probably recover some type safety with F-bounded polymorphism, but I don't fully see what you are trying to do yet.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I'm trying to enforce a certain design in all sub classes that implement the base Command interface while allowing the flexibility of each class to return different types. In other words, if the base class contains the method `public x execute()` & `public x evaluateCommandSuccess()` & `public x logBefore()` I would like to replace x with different return types while still forcing each of the 3 methods to appear in all of the classes that implement the `Command` pattern..

Comment: I don't see why you can't use generics. Just make your command generic. Result can be anything, or do all results inherit from i.e. a common interface named `Result`? Besides, sounds logical to me that every command knows its own return type...

Answer (score 4):

You can use generics to allow implementing classes to define the return type:

```
interface Command<R> {
  R execute();
  R evaluateCommandSuccess();
  R logBefore();
}

interface BooleanCommand extends Command<Boolean> {}
interface StringCommand extends Command<String> {}
interface VoidCommand extends Command<Void> {}

class BooleanCommandImpl implements BooleanCommand {
  @Override public Boolean execute() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override public Boolean evaluateCommandSuccess() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override public Boolean logBefore() {
    return true;
  }
}

class StringCommandImpl implements StringCommand {
  @Override public String execute() {
    return "STRING";
  }

  @Override public String evaluateCommandSuccess() {
    return "STRING";
  }

  @Override public String logBefore() {
    return "STRING";
  }
}

class VoidCommandImpl implements VoidCommand {
  @Override public Void execute() {
    return null;
  }

  @Override public Void evaluateCommandSuccess() {
    return null;
  }

  @Override public Void logBefore() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

However, as you can see, the `XYZCommand` interfaces are actually empty; there is no meaningful distinction between `XYZCommand` and `Command<XYZ>`: that is pretty much exactly what generics are there for.

Comment: Thanks! This solutions works well if all implementing classes returned a value - but what if I also want a `VoidCommand` (as in `public void execute()` ). In other words, I can do `BooleanCommand` extends Command but not `VoidCommand` extends Command

Comment: Unfortunately, in Java, you can't abstract over the return type that way. I consider that a serious design flaw in Java. Even more unfortunately, C♯ copied that design flaw. In Scala, it would simply be `Command[Unit]`. I have no idea what the point is with that almost-but-not-quite-a-type `void` thing in Java. Anyway, you can kinda-sorta "fake" it using `java.lang.Void` and `return null`.

Answer (score 1):

execute should not return a value. Check the concept of command/query separation. 
If you really decide to have a return object then you should encapsulate the return object in a class which you can then call getBooleanValue getStringValue

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to implement following thing

```
class Command {
   execute() {...}
}

class BooleanCommand extend Command  {
   execute() {...; return True;}
}

class StringCommand extend Command  {
   execute() {...; return "STRING";}
}
```

Then, it is possible with 'covariant return type' in Java 5+. 'Covariant return' - means when one overrides a method, the return type of the overriding method is allowed to be a subtype of the overridden method's return type. Few related discussions about it can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882584/what-is-a-covariant-return-type) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134571/covariant-return-type-in-java).

In your case we can have the following definitions working for you

```
class Command {
   public Object execute() {...; return Null;}
}

class BooleanCommand extend Command  {
   public Boolean execute() {...; return True;}
}

class StringCommand extend Command  {
   public String execute() {...; return "STRING";}
}
```

The same behavior can be observed with interfaces as well. You can do something like this and force you child classes implementing BooleanCommand and StringCommand to return their specific return types.

```
interface Command {
    public Object execute();
}

interface BooleanCommand extends Command {
    public Boolean execute();
}

interface StringCommand extends Command {
    public String execute();
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Update: I am unable to edit my previous comment but what I meant was that the only way to force `BooleanCommand` to override the return type of execute()  is to convert `BooleanCommand` to a normal class as appose to an interface and have other classes extend (not inherit) from `BooleanCommand` (otherwise `BooleanCoommand` will never be forced to override Object with its own return type..) correct? At this point, I plan on accepting this as the correct answer :)

Comment: I guess the same thing can be done with interfaces as well. I have added the interface code as well.

Comment: I see this solutions works well with classes returning a value but what about a method that is void (such as `public void execute()` ) - does it mean I need to design this class from scratch as it cannot inherit/implement the previous said interface? In other words, I can do `BooleanCommand` extends Command but not `VoidCommand` extends Command

Comment: Yes, I guess. Because the covariant return type only works on changing the return type, which are subclasses of super class return type.